# Передать массив из одного ViewController'a в другой

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Пишу приложение по типу iTunes (2 вкладки: Поиск и История).

На вкладке Поиск выдается `TableView` со списком альбомов. При нажатии на альбом открывается `ShowInfoViewController` (`ViewController` с доп. информацией по альбому).

Я хочу, чтобы в этот момент, при нажатии на альбом, кроме появления `ShowInfoViewController`, еще и отправлялись данные в `HistoryViewController`.

Как я могу просто записать в другой контроллер данные, не открывая его на `View`, как это происходит при вызове метода `present`? (Нужно каждый раз при нажатии на альбом класть данные из выбранной ячейки в `HistoryViewController`)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let album = albums[indexPath.row]
    
    let infoController =  self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "showInfo") as! ShowInfoViewController
    infoController.album = album
    self.present(infoController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
    let historyController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "history") as! HistoryViewController
    historyController.albums.append(album)
    
}
```

P.S. Если просто убрать `present`, ничего во 2 контроллер не кладется. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логично было бы получать и обновлять данные в самом `HistoryViewController` при переключении на него. Для этого данные истории можно помещать в какое-то временное (переменную с общим доступом/синглтон) или постоянное хранилище (база данных). Но если вам так хочется обновлять данные напрямую в другом вью контроллере и вы уверены, что он существует на момент уведомления, то здесь лучше воспользоваться механизмом уведомлений или делегирования, информации об этом много.

```
struct History {
    var albums: [Album]
}
```

Затем при переключении на `HistoryViewController` эти данные можно брать например во `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Благодарю! Выбрал путь через сохранение данных в CoreData

Comment: @VozmiteNaRabotu если ответ оказался полезен, поставьте возле него галку